# How to conveniently draw a background rectangle for each node over all its children in tikz trees?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, backgrounds, tikz-qtree, qtree

I have drawn a tree using `tikz-qtree` and want to draw a background rectangle for each node over its (direct) children. Now I use `\node` when drawing the tree and then manually add the background rectangles one by one; see the code and figure below. Are there any convenient ways (Image that it is a huge tree.)?

Answers using other packages than `tikz-qtree` are also appreciated.

[Editable code at ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/58e0e9a9ecdd8b8070f15332):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, fit}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree [.\node (1234567) {$n_1n_2n_3n_4n_5n_6n_7$};
      [.\node (123) {$n_1n_2n_3$};
        [.\node (1) {$n_1$}; ] 
          [.\node (23) {$n_2n_3$};
            [.\node (2) {$n_2$}; ]
            [.\node (3) {$n_3$}; ]]] 
      [.\node (4567) {$n_4n_5n_6n_7$};
        [.\node (45) {$n_4n_5$};
          [.\node (4) {$n_4$}; ] 
          [.\node (5) {$n_5$}; ]]
        [.\node (67) {$n_6n_7$};
          [.\node (6) {$n_6$}; ] 
          [.\node (7) {$n_7$}; ]]]]

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      % manually add background rectangles one by one
      \node () [rectangle, draw, fit = (2) (3), inner sep = 0pt] {};
      \node () [rectangle, draw, fit = (4) (5), inner sep = 0pt] {};
      \node () [rectangle, draw, fit = (6) (7), inner sep = 0pt] {};
      \node () [rectangle, draw, fit = (1) (23), inner sep = 0pt] {};
      \node () [rectangle, draw, fit = (45) (67), inner sep = 0pt] {};
      \node () [rectangle, draw, fit = (123) (4567), inner sep = 0pt] {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: qtree-bg]

Comment: The way you're doing it is probably the most efficient using `tikz-qtree`. If you use the `forest` package, you can avoid having to manually specify `\node{...}` in each node and instead just provide the label, so that will make the code simpler.  It wouldn't surprise me if the `forest` gurus here could automate it further.

Comment: If you were using plain `qtree.sty`, you could use the built-in frame commands it provides; e.g. `\qtreeshowframes` will put a frame around every leaf and non-terminal label, while `!\qframesubtree` will wrap a frame around the just-completed subtree. But it looks like the tag `qtree` is a bit of a mistake here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a much simpler way to do this using `forest`. I've created a node style that fits a rectangle around the children of the current node. Then using a conditional `\if nodewalk valid`, I apply the style to nodes that have daughters.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{child frame/.style=
    {tikz={\node () [rectangle, red,draw, fit to=children,inner sep = 0pt] {};}}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}for tree={if nodewalk valid={l}{child frame}{}}
   [$n_1n_2n_3n_4n_5n_6n_7$
      [$n_1n_2n_3$
              [$n_1$ ] 
          [$n_2n_3$
            [$n_2$ ]
            [$n_3$ ]]] 
      [$n_4n_5n_6n_7$
        [$n_4n_5$
          [$n_4$ ] 
          [$n_5$ ]]
        [$n_6n_7$
          [$n_6$ ] 
          [$n_7$ ]]]]
    \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Again I learned something new about `forest`! Bravo! (+1)